# echoing asterisk to file

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I have an odd problem.  I'm trying to echo the response from a file into another file.  For instance I like to use:

```
# run_location=`find -name 'program.exe'`
# echo $run_location>storagefile.txt
```

So I can save where my program is located for use later.  However now I have an issue where I want to grab the output of a program and store it.  The only issue is that the output contains a lot of asterisks  (*) and when I echo an * it echoes all of the filenames in my directory producing a file that is a mess.

The output of the file is:

```
# ./device -FD
*******************************
* Firmware         : 1.0034   *
* Date             : 011209   *
*******************************
```

And i would like to save the file verbose, is there any way around this?  Possibly some other way to save the output to a file?  I know it wasn't the best idea for them to output with asterisks, but I have no control over how I get this data back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Important rule for shell scripting: be liberal where you apply your quotes.  So for your example:

```
run_location="`find -name 'program.exe'`"
echo "$run_location" >storagefile.txt
```

Without these quotes, these get interpreted as command line tokens...  It will be chopped up based on the presence of spaces, and patterns like `*` will be evaluated.  If it comes from the user, a file, or the output of a program, quote it.

Comment: e.g. remember that it's the shell that expands the contents of variables, BEFORE trying to parse the rest of the command line. so you end up doing `echo *******....`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, still a rookie on this side of the fence.

Comment: They don't hurt, but you don't need the double quotes in the first line, even if the output you're capturing contains asterisks. You do need the quotes in the second line, though.

Comment: @Idelic - I'm not so sure I agree with you.  My memory is hazy, but I seem to recall there were shells that behaved poorly if you assign to a variable using the backtick and the command outputs a space.  In general I tend to quote anything that could yield a space out of an abundance of caution.